# Issue with maven when going to add mysql-java dependency in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jdbc

I am working on maven project to connect with Mysql using Java in eclipse. Below is my POM file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
    instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
    4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
    <mysql.verison>8.0.18</mysql.verison>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
            <!-- Mysql -->>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>$(mysql.version)</version>

        </dependency>

    </dependencies>  
</project>
```

I have added the dependency, tried with NetBeans as well but no luck.
Eclipse mark the property as red.

```xml
<properties>
<mysql.verison>8.0.18</mysql.verison>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no two `<properties>` tags in a single pom.xml file.
You have to make the property and refer it. Also syntax is wrong of reference.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <mysql-java-version>8.0.18</mysql-java-version>
</properties>
```

Refer it like this:

```
    <dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
     <version>${mysql-java-version}</version>

    </dependency>
```

Comment: i editted as you show. But still there some error nothing changed also added more error                                 
          <properties>
 <mysql.verison>8.0.18</mysql.verison>
    </properties>                                                                                                                                        project build error: Non-parseable POM  and under the code mysql marked                                                                                         <dependencies>
            <!-- Mysql -->>
        <dependency>